# Is it possible to send whitespace parameter in ASP.NET Web API?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I have a route [Route("terms/{term}")] with an action attribute:
public void Update(string term, Term user)

The question is, how can I send whitespace {term} (e.g. "   ", or "\t") to this route? Is that possible?

Comment: To clarify, are you wanting ASP.NET and the web-server to respect trailing whitespace in resource-paths?

Comment: Yes, I want to send requests such as {url}/terms/{spaces}, and recive spaces in the term parameter

Comment: I tried {url}/terms/%20, but it doesn't work :(
edit: I tried it with a Postman, maybe it doesn't handle it well

Answer (score 3):

I believe it is `%20` what you're looking for. It is the equivalent of a space.

*You can also use `+` but to be specific, it's all internal terms not used by the URL encoder.

Edit:

Add this line to your web.config:

```
<httpRuntime relaxedUrlToFileSystemMapping="true"/>
```

Comment: %20 works only when it is located between normal characters, e.g.
{url}/terms/a%20b, this works fine and parameter is initialized with "a b" value which is correct, but it doesn't work with just a space, or a trailing space.

Comment: Ah, well that's because `relaxedUrlToFileSystemMapping` is set to `false` by default. Add the line above.

Comment: But in this case spaces still do not work. Trailing spaces are just being trimmed.